# Scrapy how to recursively run a spider with dynamic (variable) argument?

Tags: python, web-crawler, twisted, scrapy

I have code a full functional spider which takes an argument `date`. Which will change on every iteration of the spider.

For testing purpouse I have created a shell script that does the following.

2. There is a dot file `.date` which is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` script reads the file and pass the date to spider.
3. Once task is finished and data is saved to mysql the date value decreased by one day and saved it on the file for the next iteration.

### Shell Script

```
lastDate=$(cat .dailyScrapeDate)
echo "Last scraped Date : $lastDate"
nextDate=$(date -d "$lastDate -1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")
echo "Next scraped Date : $nextDate"

echo "Launching Spider"
scrapy crawl dailyDataSpider -a date=$nextDate

echo "Writing scraped date ($nextDate) to dot file .dailyScrapeDate"
echo "$nextDate" > .dailyScrapeDate
```

Now I need to move it to a crawler process. So how do I proceed? Do I need to create a standalone python file and run it? For example I have created a file `process.py`

### Python Script process.py

```
from DailyDataSpider import DailyDataSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl( DailyDataSpider, date=date ) # TODO: Read and pass date
process.start()
# Save date?
```

The argument date=date is passed but I am bit confused about how to move forward after this. Do I read and write the dot file on the python file? Does this file code runs on each iteration or scrap only takes the argument once and runs with it?

**Question:** How to recursively run a spider with dynamic (variable) argument?

Answer (score 2):

This script is alright

```
from DailyDataSpider import DailyDataSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl( DailyDataSpider, date=date ) # TODO: Read and pass date
process.start()
```

Now in your spider file do this

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
class DailyDataSpider (CrawlSpider):

      def __init__(self, date=None):
             if date:
                  self.date = date
```

Now access `self.date` anywhere in your spider.
and you can access `date` in your `pipeline` or `middleware` like `spider.date`

Default None is provided in **init**() to prevent errors if we do not want to pass a date argument ... so `scrapy crawl spider1 -a date=date_here` and `scrapy crawl spider1` would work

Comment: probably should always assign `self.date`.  I'm not sure why a default of `None` is provided here but if it's useful then let downstream application code check it - instead of hitting an AttributeError when it's not set.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Default None is provided in __init__() to prevent errors if we do not want to pass a date argument ... so `scrapy crawl spider1 -a date=date_here` and `scrapy crawl spider1` would work

Comment: If the application code *requires* a date to operate then it would be a lot better for the process to fail at `scrapy crawl ...` time than at some random point later on during the crawl.  But, sure, leave the default and just unconditionally create the attribute.